# which template does wp_ tag_ cloud point to?

Tags: templates, tags, cloud

This is very embarassing.

If I add `wp_tag_cloud` to my navigation in list form, it shows as I need it (like a sub nav). If you then click a tag what template is then used?

I've tried adding **taxonomy.php**, **archive.php** and **tag.php** but it doesn't seem to use those and i'm now at a loss!

Any guidance is much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: **tag.php** should work. What theme are you using? (might consider adding that info to the question).

Comment: It's a custom theme. Sorry I didn't mention that. I tried tag.php to no avail. Do i need any special code on that template? Thanks

Comment: If the theme is not adhering to the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) then, sorry i'm not sure what to suggest without knowing more about how the theme operates.

Comment: Hi t3los, although a custom theme, I still use the standard template pages etc. It just runs my own style sheet, layout & images. Thanks

Comment: Does the same problem occur with other taxonomies? Do category archives work fine? ie. load `category.php` when you request a category?

Comment: category.php works fine. I saved & renamed it to taxonomy.php, arhive.php etc thinking it would be that simple but obviously not

Comment: Have a look at the template hierarchy link i provided in one of my earlier comments and examine what files are in place inside your theme folder, do you have any files that will take precedance over **tag.php**, such as **tag-ID.php** or **tag-slug.php** (where ID and slug would be an applicable numeric value or slug)..

Comment: No, I dont have anything like that. I've decided to try and approach it differently but can't work out one part.

If if can get the below to display to be category/term instead of taxonomy/term, I think that would work as I can use the existing category template  
        <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $cat->name, 'new_cats' ); ?>">   
 <?php echo $cat->name; ?>     
 </a>

Comment: So, if **tag.php** is emptied of all code, and you simply have `<?php echo 'This is a tag template test'; ?>` does the problem still occur when querying for a tag page?

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, no it's not showing that at all, so I'm guessing there is an issue somewhere, I just can't see where. :-(

Comment: Try with plugins disabled..  failing that i'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/) plugin, it should display name of template being used.